# Change a button color within an array to that of a different button that was just pressed in another array

Tags: c#, winforms

I would appreciate help for changing the color of a button, to the color of a different button that was just pressed. I have two arrays of buttons defined by:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Button[,] btn = new Button[8, 8];
    Button[,] btn2 = new Button[10, 20];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int x = 0; x < btn.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < btn.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                btn[x, y] = new Button();
                btn[x, y].SetBounds(40 * x, 40 * y, 40, 40);
                btn[x, y].Click += new EventHandler(this.btnEvent_click);
                Controls.Add(btn[x, y]);
                btn[x, y].BackColor = Color.Empty;
            }
        }

        for (int v = 0; v < btn2.GetLength(0); v++)
        {
            for (int w = 0; w < btn2.GetLength(1); w++)
            {
                btn2[v, w] = new Button();
                btn2[v, w].SetBounds(40 * v, 40 * w, 40, 40);
                btn2[v, w].Click += new EventHandler(this.btn2Event_click);
                Controls.Add(btn2[v, w]);
                btn2[v, w].BackColor = Color.Empty;

            }
        }
```

I can change the color of any button within `btn2` (after selecting a button from `btn`) using below:

```
void btnEvent_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Control)sender).BackColor = Color.FromName(buttonColor.colorResult);
    }

void btn2Event_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedColor = "";

        selectedColor = btn2[0,0].BackColor.ToString();

        int pFrom = selectedColor.IndexOf("[") + "[".Length;
        int pTo = selectedColor.LastIndexOf("]");

        buttonColor.colorResult = selectedColor.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);

    }
```

But as you can see it is only `btn2[0,0]`. I am looking for a way to make this work for *whichever* button I press within `btn2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in an event in a control, `sender` is usually the exact control you just interacted with. In your case there is no sign that i wouldn't always be the button you literally just clicked. All you need to do then is to cast the object back to the type you know it will be. So without any exception checks here's an example of what would work

```
void btn2Event_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get the sender as a button
    Button button = ((Button)sender);

    string selectedColor = button.BackColor.ToString();        

    int pFrom = selectedColor.IndexOf("[") + "[".Length;
    int pTo = selectedColor.LastIndexOf("]");

    buttonColor.colorResult = selectedColor.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);

}
```